# Identify text on a tombstone (Gothic type)

Tags: translation, german-to-english, blackletter

I was hoping that someone could translate the lower part of this grave, it belongs to a relative of my grandmother. We have the name and the dates, but the bottom is hard to read, especially because I don't think it is English.

[image]

Comment: Images with copyright and a URL for an ancestry business web site seem fishy to me.

Comment: It is psalm 68.5: “Der ein Vater ist der Waisen und ein Richter der Witwen.” It‘s the bible, you should find it online.

Comment: The line in between should be her age: 41 years, 10 months, 21 days (J=Jahr, M=Monat, T=Tag).

Answer (score 6):

The gravestone reads:

> Friedrich [Z?]öller
>   geb. 2 Oct. 1861
>   gest. 23 Aug. 1903
>   Alter
>   41 J. 10 M. 21 T.
>   Text Psalm 68,6
>   Der ein Vater ist der Waisen
>   und ein Richter der Witwen

which translates to

> Friedrich [Z?]öller
>   born 2nd October 1861
>   died 23rd August 1903
>   Age
>   41 years 10 months 21 days
>   Text Psalm 68,6
>   He who is a Father to the Orphans
>   and a Judge of Widows

---

*Notes.*

- I am not sure about the first letter of the family name. The name "Zöller" is pretty common, but there are other names ending in "-öller" (Wöller, Röller, Töller, Köller, etc.)
- The verse number given on the gravestone is 6, not 5. As I see it, the upper left sweep of that number is the same as that in the other sixes in the inscription; in a five that part would not have bent so far to the right and would have remained equally wide instead of tapering off. (The numbering of that verse differs between different editions of the Bible; in some editions it is 5, in others 6.)
- I translated the German words of the Psalm instead of citing an English translation of the Bible. "Father" and "Judge" are appellations of God.

Answer (score 1):

This is the beginning of psalm 68:5

> Der ein Vater ist der Waisen und ein Richter der Witwen.

which according to the English Standard Version of the Bible translates to

> Father of the fatherless and protector of widows

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed a part of a psalm in german:

> Psalm 68:5
>   Der ein Vater ist der Waisen und ein Richter der Witwen.

Translation:

> Father of the fatherless and protector of widows.

Answer (score 0):

The last two lines seem to be from [Psalm 68](http://www.bibel-online.net/buch/luther_1912/psalm/68/) in [Luther's translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luther_Bible):

> der ein Vater ist der Waisen
>   und ein Richter der Witwen

In the King James Bible:

> [who is] a father of the fatherless,
>   and a judge of the widows

I cannot completely read the line before that, but I think that it just says that it is indeed Psalm 68. (Do not mistake the [long s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_s) for an *f*.)