# Old Pennsylvania German headstone translation needed

Tags: english

[image]

The cleaned gravestone seems fairly legible. Thank you!

Comment: The site doesn't really like induvidual translation requests. Type in the text, try to translate it with google translate and ask what is not okay.

Comment: New users can't include pictures into the question, this is a spam protection. I inserted it for you. Maybe you will get a translation from somebody in a comment, but honestly, I don't think that anybody would be happy trying to decipher the text on it. I suggest to paste the text, to make the work of the translators easier.

Comment: Another thing: nobody likes the questions from which it is very well visible, that the asker didn't want to spent even a half minute in them.

Comment: Other very similar Questions did not get closed. I vote for keeping this open

Comment: This one and several similar didn't get closed. please explain the incoherence. https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/32642/identify-text-on-a-tombstone-gothic-type

Comment: @Beta: Es gibt kein gleiches Recht im Unrecht. Wenn es um das Entziffern der Buchstaben geht, müsste der Frager in Vorleistung gehen. Da dieser Stein anderen Leuten mit ähnlichen Fragen nicht hilft ihren Stein zu entziffern ist er ein zu individuelles Problem. Wenn das bei anderen Fragen auch schon so war ist es ein Grund diese auch zu schließen - nicht diese hier offen zu lassen.

Comment: @userunknown, ok, dann nehme ich meine Re-Open-Stimme zurück.

Comment: @Beta Die vergleichbaren Fragen waren nach "helft mir, das zu entziffern", nicht "helft mir das zu übersetzen" - erstere haben wir beschlossen, als on-topic zu werten, diese Schrift ist aber mMn sehr leicht zu lesen und ich sehe auch absolut keine Deutsch-spezifischen Schwierigkeiten daran.

Comment: @tofro Schon ich als Deutsch Muttersprachler finde es äußerst beschwerlich eine undeutliche Frakturschrift zu entziffern, zumal es hier, wie an den Antworten zu erkennen, Deutungsklippen gibt. Wie soll man da einfach herangehen? Von daher klar ein Reopen.

Answer (score 6):

Still not terribly legible, and it would have been helpful if you had linked to the [memorial page](https://www.findagrave.com/memorial/43344221/magdelena-keim) instead of just the picture, but here goes:

```
hier ruhet                  here lies
der ??? Leichnam            the ??? body
von Magdalene Keim          of Magdalene Keim
eine geborne                born
Hochin                      Hoch
wurde geboren               born 
im December 1736            in December 1736
und starb                   and died
den 21. April 1804          April 21, 1804
war alt worden              reached the age of
73 Jahre 4 Monate           73 years, 4 months
```

Comment: So grateful for the help! I will add your translation to the findagrave site.

Answer (score 5):

To complete the answer of @microtherion:
The word before Leichnam is "entselte" (modern spelling: entseelte), which means the body has lost it's spirit.
"Eine geborene Hochin" means her maiden name was "Hoch". It was common practice to use the feminine suffix -in on the surname for women.

Comment: Wow, very much appreciated. My husband's 6th GGrandmother.

Comment: Ah, brilliant! I'd been racking my brain what that word could have been — clearly the formula called for something similar to "mortal". "entseelte" makes indeed perfect sense.